# Store BitSet in App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

What is the best way to store a BitSet in App engine?  They don't allow java.util.BitSet to be a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BitSet` is `Serializable`.  Datastore can get/put `Serializable` [just fine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html#Serializable_Objects).

Comment: Then why do I get the error java.util.BitSet is not a supported property type.

Comment: @Lumpy: did you add annotations described in that link?  i.e. - `@Persistent(serialized = "true")`?  `BitSet` is definitely on the whitelist.

Answer (score 2):

Try [EnumSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)

"A specialized Set implementation for use with enum types. All of the elements in an enum set must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the set is created. **Enum sets are represented internally as bit vectors.** This representation is extremely compact and efficient. The space and time performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit flags." Even bulk operations (such as containsAll and retainAll) should run very quickly if the specified collection is also an enum set."

Comment: can I easily create a BitSet from an ENUM set?

Comment: I don't think this answer makes sense.  Lumpy wants to store an arbitrary length `BitSet` (as far as I can tell) - that means making an arbitrary length `enum` to make the `EnumSet` from to adequately store his data - that seems anathema to the point of `enum` types.

Answer (score 0):

java.math.BigInteger supports common bit set operations and can be serialized to a byte array.